# How to split string and assign them to struct

Tags: c

I am trying to split a string by `,` and assign them to a struct.

Example string

```c
char t1[] = "185213,Example Name,88";
```

And I have this struct.

```c
typedef struct {
    int studentNumber;
    char studentName[200];
    int grade;
} STUDENT;
STUDENT students[]= {
    {...},
    {...},
    {...}
}
```

I want to split the string and push into students struct array. I mean 185213 is number, Example Name is name and 88 is grade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know up front that your strings will **always** have just three fields, with the format
**"%d,%s,%d"**, then you do not need a complex logic with loops, and input checking, and so on. Something simpler has parsing each element separately would be enough:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct {
    int studentNumber;
    char *studentName;
    int grade;
} STUDENT;

int main(){  
    STUDENT *student = malloc(sizeof(STUDENT));
    student->studentName = malloc(201); // Space for 200 characters + '\0'
    char *eptr;
    
     char t1[] = "185213,Example Name,88";
     char *token = strtok(t1, ",");                       // Read studentNumber
     student-> studentNumber = strtol(token, &eptr, 10);
     token = strtok(NULL, ",");                           // Read the studentName
     strcpy(student->studentName, token);
     token = strtok(NULL, ",");                          // Read the grade
     student-> grade = strtol(token, &eptr, 10);
          
     printf("%d\n", student-> studentNumber);
     printf("%s\n", student-> studentName);
     printf("%d\n", student-> grade);
     ... 
}
```

You can use the function [strtok](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm) to parse the strings based on the delimiter `","`, the function [strcpy](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strcpy.htm) to copy the strings parsed from `strtok` into your `struct`, and the function [strtol](https://www.techonthenet.com/c_language/standard_library_functions/stdlib_h/strtol.php) to parser the `int` value from the string read from `strtok`.

A difference between the `STUDENT` `struct` that I have posted and yours, is that the field `char *studentName` was dynamically allocated (as correctly pointed out on the comments).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this like so (using `atoi()` from `stdlib.h` and `strcpy` from `string.h`).

```
char t1[] = "185213,Example Name,88";    
char * pch;

STUDENT s;
pch = strtok (t1,",");
if (pch != NULL) s.studentNumber = atoi(pch);

pch = strtok (NULL,",");
if (pch != NULL) strcpy(s.studentName, pch);   

pch = strtok (NULL,",");
if (pch != NULL) s.grade = atoi(pch);
```